# messenger API error code 190

Tags: facebook, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have ran into one messenger error that after month or two, access token becomes not valid.

I am getting long lived access token for facebook page:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

And I am using it for messenger queries, to send messages.
But after month or two, I am getting same errors, that facebook changed session or user changed password(which is not true). Here is error:

```
Error:  { message: 'Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user changed their password or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons.',
type: 'OAuthException',
code: 190,
error_subcode: 460,
fbtrace_id: 'trace_id' }
```

The issue is after this, no messages are sent. And we need valid access token.

Is there anyway, we can do this on server side without user interaction?

Or maybe somehow always to renew access token with every time user interacts?

Is there any way around this?

Comment: _“I am getting long lived access token for facebook page”_ - no, you’re not - not with that call, passing in a page token already. That is not how the process of generating an extended page token works. Go read up on it in the manual, it is described in there in detail.

Comment: Not sure what you talking. Doing all same as from this example:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension/
Just instead short-lived-access-token I am using page access token, which I got from JS SDK, while user was using web app